# How to specify additional parameters in R functions?

Tags: r, list, arguments

For Fitting Markov Switching Models with package MSwM (function msmFit) there is 'control' argument which is list of control parameters.
Syntax of msmFit is:

msmFit(object, k, sw, p, data, family, control)

The 'control' argument is a list that can supply any of the following components:

-trace: A logical value. If it is TRUE, tracing information on the progress of the optimization is produced.

-maxiter: The maximum number of iterations in the EM method. Default is 100.
and so on.

My question is how to specify for example '-maxiter'? I tried: component(maxiter=50), component-maxiter=50, component[["maxiter"]]=50. Everything gives an error. "unexpected '='" or other errors connected to argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format your call something like this:

```
mod=msmFit(model,k=2,sw=rep(TRUE,8),control=list(maxiter=10))
```